# Android - Enabling and Disabling Send Email Button

Tags: android

In my application, there is a button that connects the app to mail applications for sending an email. I'm trying to disable the button after clicking one time but I couldn't understand where should I enable the button again which causes no problem. Here is my code:

```
 tvAboutEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","something@gmail.com", null));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending With:"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you try `setEnabled`?

Comment: You can enable the button on method `onResume` on your activity. Or you can create a thread that enable the button after n seconds. But this business logic decision that you have to make.

Comment: @AsfK of course. the problem is I don't know where should I put setEnabled(true)

Comment: @easyjoin.net thanks it worked for me. you should write it in answers so I check the accept button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the button on method `onResume` on your activity. Or you can create a thread that enable the button after n seconds. But this business logic decision that you have to make.

Answer (score 0):

Put `tvAboutEmail.setEnable(false)` inside your onclick, this will disable the listener.
You can enable it after a certain time like 2 or 3 seconds with an Handler

Answer (score 0):

You can either use attribute that blocks the action, but resets after application closes like

```
private boolean hasBeenSent = false;
```

and then do this

```
 tvAboutEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!hasBeenSent){
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                "mailto","something@gmail.com", null));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending With:"));
        hasBeenSent = true;
        }
    }
});
```

or use SharedPreferences to store that value even after app closes

```
 tvAboutEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPref = getSharedPreferences(TAG,MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!mSharedPref.getBoolean("hasBeenSent",false)){
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                "mailto","something@gmail.com", null));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending With:"));
        mSharedPref.edit().putBoolean("hasBeenSent",true).commit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what if the user presses the button, then when choosing email app window came, cancels sending, then presses it again? it won't work for the second time.

Comment: I'd look into startActivityForResult and then check it in onActivityResult. Not sure if it'll work tho

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
      tvAboutEmail.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

And add the following inside your onClickListener()

```
tvAboutEmail.setEnabled(false);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

This will enable your button 2 seconds after being clicked.